# Qual é a diferença entre um arquivo XML e um Arquivo XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Sabemos que estes dois tipos de arquivos estão correlacionados - `.XSD e XML`.

- *Qual é diferença entre os dois?*
- *Pra que serve um `.XML`(Extensible Markup Language) e o `.XSD`?*
- É possível se trabalhar com um XML sem um XSD?

Answer (score 9):

Os dois arquivos utilizam a sintaxe de *XML*. A diferença é que o *XSD* é utilizado para validar um *XML*, quais campos o *XML* deverá conter, quais seus tipos, se são obrigatórios ou não, dentre outros.

Há outras respostas para complementar **[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334009/3797668)**.

Answer (score 9):

O XSD é o arquivo que define a estrutura de dados.
O XML é o arquivo que contém os dados.
Sim é possível trabalhar com um XML sem o XSD, mas é recomendável que você tenha um XSD.

Por exemplo, no XSD posso dizer que existe um campo chamado Data_de_Nascimento, que pode ser preenchido como nulo.

No arquivo XML caso o campo Data_de_Nascimento não seja preenchido o mesmo pode não ser apresentado.

No caso da integração de um sistema fortemente tipado, caso o programador se baseie em um XML que veio sem Data_de_Nascimento para criar suas classes, terá uma infeliz surpresa quando começar a vir XMLs contendo Data_de_Nascimento.

Então para assegurar a validade dos dados como disse nosso colega Daniel, utilizamos o XSD, que muitos chamam de Schema.